# Is it safe to call mount(2) and pass the password as a parameter?

Tags: linux, password-management, c, file-system

I wanted to write a daemon that users can start, and that, every 2 hours, automatically mounts an authenticated network share. The daemon will prompt the user for the password only the first time, and it will keep it `mlock()`ed then.

My idea was to somehow call the linux program `mount(1)` (manpage notation). The protocol for the mounting (in my case samba) only allows to give the password via the mount options `-o` [1]. However, passing the password as a parameter to a shell script makes it visible in the ps-table.

Then, I found out that there's a linux system call `mount(2)` that takes the same parameters. Is it safe to simply pass the password as plaintext to `mount(2)`'s parameters?

Things I worry about:

- `mount(2)` might be implemented by calling a process where it passes the arguments, including the password. This would leave the password in the ps-table. However, I think system calls won't do that?
- `mount(2)` might have its parameters in non-`mlock()`ed memory, e.g. if the system swaps, the plaintext password is readable on disk. I don't know if a system-calls memory can be swapped, but since the mount call is only active for a short time, I guess this is no real issue.
- `mount(2)` might (maybe depending on the file system type) print error or log messages exposing its parameters. (e.g. in system files like `/var/log/messages` or the `dmesg` output). At least, I just tested `mount(2)` with the `MS_SILENT` flag and did not find any system logs, even on failure.

All in all, how safe is my solution?

Notes: [1] Samba also allows plaintext authentication files or typing the password at a prompt, but that was not useful in my case.

Comment: Unrelated to the question but you say: *the daemon will prompt the user for the password*. A daemon has normally no user interaction. I assume you meant *the program starting the daemon will ask the user for the password and pass it to the daemon through a pipe*

Comment: Wrong word, what I actually meant was a program that the user would start and which will run in the background until the end of a session. Passing this information to an already running program (deamon) would seem a bit more complicated in terms of security.

Answer (score 1):

1. *mount(2) might be implemented by calling a process* it is just the opposite: `mount(1)` is a front end ultimately calling `mount(2)` which being a system call asks the kernel to do the job
2. *mount(2) might have its parameters in non-mlock()ed memory* unsure of it, but why do you think that `mlock` memory is secure? AFAIK root can read /dev/mem and /dev/kmem as (more?) easily as the content of the swap partition...
3. *mount(2) might (maybe depending on the file system type) print error or log messages exposing its parameters* it would indeed be a security threat, and I do not know any network mount utility ever logging a password in clear text. Anyway as said in 1, any attempt to mount the network share will ultimately end in a `mount(2)` call so you cannot avoid it.

TL/DR: it is far more secure to call `mount(2)` that starting a subprocess to call `mount(1)` because the parameters passed to the subprocess command will be accessible through the process table and can be displayed with `ps` with the appropriate options and the error condition processing will be much simpler.

Comment: you say calling `mount(2)` is more secure than calling `mount(1)`, but is it "secure enough"/good practice?

Comment: @Johannes: You can safely use all functions from the standard library (3) and all system calls (2) in your code. Just read carefully the man pages, it there is a caveat, it will be referenced. As a rule of thumb, use commands (1) and (8) when you develop shells and functions (3) and (2) when you develop C (or C++) programs